# Win XP IE8 Show blank pages on some the website

Tags: windows, windows-xp, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

When I go onto some of the pages in IE8, I get blank pages.
e.g. Windows Update, Google Maps, Adobe

Also, when I click on some of the download click I get redirected to same page.

I have done this:

- Remove IE8 run clean up tools e.g. ccleaner
- Re-install IE8.
- Reset IE8.
- Run `SFC /scannow`.

Later today, I will try to reinstall SP3 again.

Please help, thank you.

Comment: Just in case it helps anyone, I had the same problem and was related to: [IE8 overflow:auto with max-height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707/ie8-overflowauto-with-max-height)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions from [Internet Explorer 7/8 shows blank page or just background of page](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/InternetExplorer/thread/555b62ed-b472-4ce6-b940-e07c69bab4cf):

1. Internet Options / Miscellaneous, enable Allow META REFRESH
2. Tools / Internet Options / Advanced tab, check "Automatically recover from rendering errors with Compatibility View"

Comment: I have try this but still blank pages on some of the sites. i even can't download google chrome, it keep going to download page again and again when you click on download.

Comment: I would verify system integrity using [sfc /scannow](http://www.pcug.org.au/boesen/SFC/SFC.htm). You need a boot CD of the same service pack as installed, or follow the instructions in the article for slip-streaming.

Comment: i do have win xp sp3 cd but nothing happened. samething still happening.

Comment: Next step is antivirus scan, using your installed anti-virus and also *well-known* (only) sites by googling "online antivirus scan". You can trust ESET, TrendMicro, Kaspersky (each will take hours).

Comment: i will try that.

Comment: run scan nothing found. still having same problem. please help can't think of anything else i can try.

Comment: This was a bit fast - doing several scans with several engines should have taken you the whole day. Anyway, the next steps are : (1) Try "Internet Explorer (No Add-ons)" which is invoked by `"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"  -extoff`. (2) Boot in Safe mode and see if the problem is still there.

Comment: i did do that but still nothing happen i was having same problem.

Comment: I can't run in safe mode as laptop is with a user who is in another country.

Comment: Virsu scan i do that before i posted on this website. sorry i forgot to put it.

Comment: I have found a fix for this it was java script which was for some reason not running.

Comment: regsvr32 wuapi.dll
regsvr32 wups.dll
regsvr32 wuaueng.dll
regsvr32 wucltui.dll
regsvr32 msxml3.dll
regsvr32 jscript